# What's the best way to make EXISTS query in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to check if a query (filter) is not empty, something like this in PostgreSQL:

```
select EXISTS(select 1 from tab where tab.name = 'abc')
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-subquery.html

My current approach in AQL is:

```
RETURN LENGTH(for d in tab filter d.name = 'abc' RETURN 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-query `FOR d IN tab FILTER d.name == 'abc'` may find a matching document early on, but will continue looking for more because there is no limit defined. Therefore, I would recommend:

```
RETURN LENGTH(FOR d IN tab FILTER d.name == 'abc' LIMIT 1 RETURN true) > 0
```

This would return `[ true ]` as query result.

You could also `RETURN d` [starting from v3.4.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arangodb/arangodb/3.4/CHANGELOG). The optimizer rule `optimize-subqueries` recognizes the pattern `LENGTH(... RETURN doc)` and replaces `doc` with a constant value `true`.